# What is the complexity of producing a unique list vs. using a set(list(*zip(..)))?

Tags: python, set, time-complexity

What is the complexity of this basic algorithm:

```
import csv
with open('texts.csv', 'r') as f:
    reader = csv.reader(f)
    texts = list(reader)

## Evaluate complexity from here
print(f"There are {len(set(list(zip(*texts))[0]))} different telephone numbers in the records.")
## end
```

and how does it compare to this more simpler version

```
phone_book = []
for phone_number, _, _ in texts:
    if phone_number not in phone_book:
        phone_book.append(phone_number)
print(f"There are {len(phone_book)} different telephone numbers in the records.")
```

My first guess is that both approaches are `O(n)` where n is the number of elements in the list.

Comment: The second approach is `O(n^2)`, `phone_book` is a list, search for an item in a list has `O(n)` complexity you do it `n` times so  `O(n^2)`.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe I'm a bit too late but I will try to answer anyways.

The first example is O(n) because you are:

1. `texts = list(reader)` => Building a list of tuples (phone, _, _) which is O(n) in the number of items in texts.csv
2. `list(zip(*texts))` => Then you build 3 element list `[[phonenumbers], [..], [..]]`, which is O(n) as before.
3. `set(...[0])` => Lastly you build the phone set from the first inner list, which is O(m)=O(1/3 * n)=O(n)

The second one is O(n²) as RaySteam pointed out because you're iterating the phonelist every time you want to add a new element.

With that being said, although the first approach is O(n) you are iterating over the data 4 times which is so much for the purpose of getting how many unique numbers you got. In that sense you may consider the approach below that only iterates once to create the desired set:

```
import csv
with open('texts.csv', 'r') as f:
    reader = csv.reader(f)
    texts = set(x for x, _1, _2 in reader)

print(f"There are {len(texts)} different telephone numbers in the records.")
```